# ASP.NET Core View error in Microsoft Tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2005

Following this [Microsoft Tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-views) on ASP.NET Core web app I'm getting the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Note**: `EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb` is the name of the project and it appears in the intellisense but the `.Models.Blog` part does not appear in the intellisense.

A portion of the view is shown below. The entire view can be seen in the above link. The error occurs in the first line of the view. I even tried `@using EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models` as a first line of the view but still the same error. What I or the Tutorial is missing? I've carefully checked the spellings and just copied/pasted the code from the tutorial to make sure the spellings are correct:

```
@model IEnumerable<EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb.Models.Blog>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blogs";
}

<h2>Blogs</h2>

........
```

I'm using the latest version of `ASP.NET Core 1.0 and VS2015-Update 3` [released on June 27, 2016] on Windows 8.1

Comment: Go to the blog model, copy the namespace and write @using namespace

Comment: @SaketChoubey Thank you, its' working now. Do you want to add your comment as a response? I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you get exception like are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?, Go to the model class, copy the namespaces and write @using namespaces. This helps to resolve namespaces issues.